# How to discard certain portion of CSV file using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have this kind of CSV file which I have to parse in Java.

```
2012-11-01 00,  1106,   2194.1971066908
2012-11-01 01,  760,    1271.8460526316
.
.
.
2012-11-30 21,  1353,   1464.0014781966
2012-11-30 22,  1810,   1338.8331491713
2012-11-30 23,  1537,   1222.7826935589
        
720 rows selected.      
        
Elapsed: 00:37:00.23
```

This is Java code I created in order to segregate each column and store it in a list.

```
public void extractFile(String fileName){
        try{
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            try {
                String readBuff = bf.readLine();
                
                while (readBuff!=null){
                    
                    Pattern checkData = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
                    Matcher match = checkData.matcher(readBuff);
                    
                    if (match.find()){
                        readBuff = null;
                    }
                    
                    else if (!match.find()){
                        
                        String[] splitReadBuffByComma = new String[3];
                        splitReadBuffByComma = readBuff.split(",");
                        
                            for (int x=0; x<splitReadBuffByComma.length; x++){
                                
                                if (x==0){
                                    dHourList.add(splitReadBuffByComma[x]);
                                }
                                else if (x==1){
                                    throughputList.add(splitReadBuffByComma[x]);
                                }
                                else if (x==2){
                                    avgRespTimeList.add(splitReadBuffByComma[x]);
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    
                    readBuff = bf.readLine();
                }
            }
            finally{
                bf.close();
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found dude: "+ e);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error Exception dude: "+e);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the regex I created is a bit faulty because it still includes the text "720 rows selected" and stores them in dHourList. 
 dHourList should only store the date column represented like this "2012-11-01 00...etc" 
throughputList = "1106, 760 ...etc" 
 avgResponseTime = "2194.192, 1271.846...etc"

What should be the correct reg expression for this?

## Update

2012-11-30 21
2012-11-30 22
2012-11-30 23

720 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:37:00.23

Size of date-hour: 724 size of throughput: 720 size of avg resp time: 720

I used this in checkData regex instead because if I use one slash \d compile will say invalid escape sequence

```
Pattern checkData = Pattern.compile("^(19|20)\\d\\d([-/.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b.+$");
```

but its still showing 720 rows selected and another line which shouldn't be there.

## Update 2

Working code:

```
while (readBuff!=null){
                    
                    
                    Pattern checkData = Pattern.compile("^(19|20)\\d\\d([-/.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\b.+$");
                    
                    Matcher match = checkData.matcher(readBuff);
                    
                    if (!match.find()){
                        readBuff = null;
                    }
                    
                    else{
                        
                        String[] splitReadBuffByComma = new String[3];
                        splitReadBuffByComma = readBuff.split(",");
                        
                            for (int x=0; x<splitReadBuffByComma.length; x++){
                                
                                if (x==0){
                                    dHourList.add(splitReadBuffByComma[x]);
                                }
                                else if (x==1){
                                    throughputList.add(splitReadBuffByComma[x]);
                                }
                                else if (x==2){
                                    avgRespTimeList.add(splitReadBuffByComma[x]);
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    
                    readBuff = bf.readLine();
                }
```

I removed else if condition and changed it to else and used the regex suggested by Cylian
now I have the output

```
2012-11-30 21
2012-11-30 22
2012-11-30 23

Size of date-hour: 720 size of throughput: 720 size of avg resp time: 720
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: See http://commons.apache.org/csv/.

Comment: We are not allowed to use 3rd party APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this [your code, but a bit modified]:**

```
public void extractFile(String fileName){
        try{
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            try {
                String readBuff = bf.readLine();

                while (readBuff!=null){

                    Pattern checkData = Pattern.compile("^(19|20)\\d\\d([-/.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\b.+$");
                    Matcher match = checkData.matcher(readBuff);

                    if (!match.find()){
                        readBuff = null;
                    }

                    else if (match.find()){

                        String[] splitReadBuffByComma = new String[3];
                        splitReadBuffByComma = readBuff.split(",");

                            for (int x=0; x<splitReadBuffByComma.length; x++){

                                if (x==0){
                                    dHourList.add(splitReadBuffByComma[x]);
                                }
                                else if (x==1){
                                    throughputList.add(splitReadBuffByComma[x]);
                                }
                                else if (x==2){
                                    avgRespTimeList.add(splitReadBuffByComma[x]);
                                }
                            }
                    }

                    readBuff = bf.readLine();
                }
            }
            finally{
                bf.close();
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found dude: "+ e);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error Exception dude: "+e);
        }
    }
```

**regex anatomy**

```
# ^(19|20)\d\d([-/.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b.+$
# 
# Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks
# 
# Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(19|20)»
#    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «19»
#       Match the characters “19” literally «19»
#    Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «20»
#       Match the characters “20” literally «20»
# Match a single digit 0..9 «\d»
# Match a single digit 0..9 «\d»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([-/.])»
#    Match a single character present in the list “-/.” «[-/.]»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(0[1-9]|1[012])»
#    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «0[1-9]»
#       Match the character “0” literally «0»
#       Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]»
#    Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «1[012]»
#       Match the character “1” literally «1»
#       Match a single character present in the list “012” «[012]»
# Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 2 «\2»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])»
#    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «0[1-9]»
#       Match the character “0” literally «0»
#       Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]»
#    Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[12][0-9]»
#       Match a single character present in the list “12” «[12]»
#       Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
#    Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «3[01]»
#       Match the character “3” literally «3»
#       Match a single character present in the list “01” «[01]»
# Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
# Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+»
#    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```

**UPDATE**

As long I understand, your input string contains many lines starts with a date but not contains commas in them. For this change the previous Pattern to this following:

```
^(19|20)\d\d([-/.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s+\d+,[^,]+,[^,]+$
```

or *`escaped`*

```
^(19|20)\\d\\d([-/.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\s+\\d+,[^,]+,[^,]+$
```

Comment: hi I tried your suggestion and I displayed dHourList contents. Its still displaying "720 rows selected and Elapsed: .....". Also I edited the regex you suggested check new update.

Comment: Hi i was able to make it work. Your solution did work but it just requires a few changes here and there. See update 2. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would make sense to insert a `^` at the beginning of your `checkData` regex. Then the expression will only be looked for at the start of the line and not in the whole string, should make it faster.

You could have your regex start with a more date format like expression (like 4 numbers and a dash), as in the last line, there will never be a dash after the number of rows.

Maybe something like this:

`Pattern checkData = Pattern.compile("^\\d\\d\\d\\d-");`

If you're sure that you don't get unexpected data, this should be sufficient - if you want to make sure that your program works even if you have malformed csv data, just extend the regular expression to capture the whole line and use `matches()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to do it with regex. (***if it shows as your example***)

you could check either

- if the line contains comma "`,`" or
- if the splitted array has length 3 or
- change a bit on the while condition, if the line ends with "`selected`.", jump out.

Comment: hi thanks for answering, I did try to experiment on placing lots of if conditions inside while loop sort of state transition. But i couldn't get it to work. I was hoping regex would solve my problem.